# Updating one particular data updates the entire record in MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna update just one data from a record using php form but the thing is, when i do that, the rest of the data gets removed from the record.. What do i do :/ here are my codes for updating. What is the mistake i am making.. I am very confused. Would really appreciate some help.

```
<?php

include('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

   $hostname = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $databaseName = "winc sports";

   $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);



   $id = $_POST['id'];
   $fname = $_POST['fname'];
   $lname = $_POST['lname'];
   $age = $_POST['age'];
   $country=$_POST['country'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];

    $select = "SELECT * FROM studens WHERE id = '$id'"; 
    $selected = mysqli_query($connect, $select); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selected); 
    if (empty($_POST['fname'])) {$fname = $row['fname'];} else {$fname = $_POST['fname'];}
    if (empty($_POST['country'])) 
    {
    $country = $row['country'];
    } 
    else {
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    }
    if (empty($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $row['id'];
        } 
    else {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    }
    if (empty($_POST['age'])) {$age = $row['age'];} else {$age = $_POST['age'];}
    if (empty($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $row['phone'];} else {$phone = $_POST['phone'];}
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {$email = $row['email'];} else {$email = $_POST['email'];}
   $query = "UPDATE students SET Fname= '$fname', Lname = '$lname', Nationality = '$country', PhoneNumber = '$phone', Email= '$email', Age = '$age' WHERE Id = '$id'";

   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
   var_dump($result);
   if($result)
   {
       echo 'Data Updated';
   }else
   {
       echo 'Data Not Updated';
   }
   mysqli_close($connect);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>PHP INSERT DATA USING PDO</title>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="updating.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id"  placeholder="Enter new ID"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="fname"  placeholder="Enter new First Name"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="lname"  placeholder="Enter new Last Name"><br><br>
    <input type="number" name="age"  placeholder="Enter new age" min="13" max="90"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="country"  placeholder="Enter new Nationality"><br><br>
    <input type="number" name="phone"  placeholder="Enter new Phone Number"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="email"  placeholder="Enter new Email"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
    </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The title of your page is wrong, `PHP INSERT DATA USING PDO` you are using `mysqli`. You also are using it in a dangerous manner, use parameterized queries. I would build the query dynamically and only update the columns that are changed.

Comment: You should `var_dump($row);` to see if it's what you expect it to be. Based on your `UPDATE` statement, I wouldn't be surprised if your result indexes are `$row['Fname']`, `$row['Lname']`, etc.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM studens` also seems like it'd cause everything to break since your `UPDATE` is to  `students`. Use error reporting. Putting in typo closure vote..

Comment: @chris85 still not working.. Can u demonstrate a correct version of it for me please? I am new to php

Comment: @PatrickQ its not showing me anything

Comment: Look at `studens`  specifically stude**ns**. What do you want an example of parameterized queries? Error reporting?

Comment: @chris85 yea fixed that but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

The select statement is fetching data from a table called **studens**.  This looks like a typo of the actual table so it won't actually fetch any results for you to update.  Thus, the data you wind up updating the table with is empty.  Rename the initial select table to **students** and it should properly fetch the data.

Also, please look into prepared statements or various other methods to sanitize inputs.  Using POST variables directly in a query makes you extremely vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: fixed that but still no luck :/

Comment: What do you get when you dump the row you select? Is there data present? Have you validated all of your column names that you're using.  The $row variables you're referring to are different from what you're updating (you refer to $row["phone"] but inserting to PhoneNumber.  Country is also Nationality in the update but you're looking for $row["country"].  If the actual column name is PhoneNumber or Nationality, then $row["phone"] and $row["country"] will always be empty.  Double check all spelling and casing for the columns you refer to.